# Error in virtualbox and genymotion when running virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

this is the error when im trying to run the virtual machine.
[image]

my virtualbox version : `4.3.26`

genymotion : 2.4.0

error in geny : [image]

also, this is on virualbox v `4.3.12` //suggested by genymotion :

[image]

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In case of Virtualbox's error of Kernel Driver, you can refer to this Virtualbox [forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=46845) page, where this issue is resolved, by installing missing system drivers.